# Object permissions with read only access for anonymous users in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-rest-framework, anonymous-users

**The problem**

I am using Django REST Framework - and so far I have been using the `DjangoObjectPermissions` permissions class. I use `django-rules` to determine which users have permissions for objects.

However, this permissions class seems to deny read access to anonymous users.

I need to find the best way to allow read-only access to all users (authenticated or not). For additions,  modifications and deletions - the object permissions should be applied as normal.

What is the best approach to solving this problem? Django does not seem to provide a `can_view` permission by default.

Perhaps this will involve manually adding a `can_view` permission for each model. Or maybe it's better to somehow implement a `DjangoObjectPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly` permissions class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix was actually really simple. It's possible to create a custom permissions class extending `DjangoObjectPermissions`, and to override the `authenticated_users_only` variable.

```
class DjangoObjectPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly(DjangoObjectPermissions):
    authenticated_users_only = False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from rest_framework import permissions
```

and Just give

```
 permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, YourPermissionshere, ]
```

in your viewset. That will do the job. 
if not authenticated,  Anonymous users will be getting a read-only permission

you can control when the permissions are checked and not checked by handling the function

```
self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
```

Comment: permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, YourPermissionsHere ]

Comment: From the DRF Permissions documentation, it sounds like the user has to have permissions in ALL of the permissions classes in order for the check to pass? So, in this case `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` would pass but `YourPermissionsHere` = `DjangoObjectPermissions` would fail? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. All permissions classes should satisfy. you can try the same. It should work.

Comment: Sorry but I've tried this and it doesn't work. Anonymous users are refused permission due to the other permissions classes.